# How to count total number of requests (links) to a site in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, usage-statistics

I want to add a panel that shows site access stats to a Rails 3 application (as in Google Analytics).  A naïve method to do this is to record IP addresses into a designated table with their access times.

Is there a function or a callback that is called at each request?  If not, is there any other way I can count the total number of accesses to a Rails 3 application?

Answer (score 4):

The "callback" you're looking for is a simple `before_filter` applied inside your application controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :log_request

  protected

  def log_request
    # Write request information to the database or log file
  end 
end
```

You are correct in calling this a very naive approach though. You could also simply analyze your log files to obtain the same information.

Comment: If my goal was to analyze only, log files would be enough.  However, I also want to display it to the users within the application itself, as it's collected.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old but when someone would like to know:

(total times) = Request.count